# Is it possible to copy a macro from one Excel workbook to another using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy a macro from one Excel workbook to another using VBA. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP051994121033.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project/HP453044431033.aspx

http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/copy-vba-module.php

Comment: hi, i have created a file using macro and added a button on that, the button still referenced to the old file. can you please suggest.