# Excel Event not working properly

Tags: vba, excel, event-handling

Hello I am working on a macro that creates a new workbook and copies some information. Everything is working fine however I added an event, to highlight the color of the value depending if it was bigger or smaller than what it was before. The even was working perfectly until I realize the events dont work if i close and re open the sheet. So i tweeked my code a little bit to make it work. Now it only works when I re open the newworkbook but when I ran the macro and the new sheet opens and try to change a value I get the following error: Method 'Undo' of object '_Application' failed.

In order to make the events work I created a class of work book an added the application as follows:

```
 Public WithEvents m_events As Application
```

here is my sub for the change which works fine when re opening:

```
Private Sub m_wb_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
m_events.EnableEvents = False
m_wb.Sheets("sheet1").Unprotect
Dim oldval As Double
Dim newval As Double
    If Sh.name = "Sheet1" And Not IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then
    newval = Target.Value
    m_events.Undo
    oldval = Target.Value
    Target.Value = newval
    If Target.Value > oldval Then Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    If Target.Value < oldval Then Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
    'MsgBox (oldval)
End If
m_wb.Sheets("sheet1").Protect
m_events.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

When I create my sheet I use the following on the workbook that created the new sheet, I created a function to create the sheet:

```
Set Newbook.Workbook = AddNew
Set Newbook.m_events = Application
```

On the new sheet I have a button and when pressed I have the following line that only works when i close and re open the new sheet.

```
Set Newbook.Workbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set Newbook.m_events = Application
Set thisWB = Newbook.Workbook
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you created your own worksheet change event and you don't use the one provided by Excel? When creating a new sheet you could easily copy the macro over from another sheet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595079/is-it-possible-to-copy-a-macro-from-one-excel-workbook-to-another-using-vba

Comment: I suspect unprotecting the sheet clears the undo stack.

Comment: Unprotecting the sheet shouldn't clear the undo stack. Protecting the sheet will. I tested this with short macros and was able to use Application.Undo after unprotecting a previously protected sheet

Comment: This would be easier to try to answer if I had a better idea of what order this all happened in and what the process was. As it is, I have no idea when this event is happening and on what sheet and when that sheet is being created.

Comment: Hello @Ralph Thank you for replying, in regards to your question. I created the workbook from the macro and wanted to add events. I found a tutorial that stated to create your own events function, i forget the link where I got it from. Thank you for the idea tho def copying over would of been great choice too

Comment: Hello @asp8811, The macro first creates the workbook and add the workbook class I created. The event code is located inside this class. this create happens on a function called templatecreat() which also adds a button. The button calls on another function called get data and this is where we see the Set Newbook.Workbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set Newbook.m_events = Application
Set thisWB = Newbook.Workbook

Comment: I dont think is the protecting and the unprotecting of the sheet. the reason is because when I create the workbook and close it right away without pressing the get data button and re open it it works perfect

Comment: Hello sorry for the multiple messages, I found a work around when I close the original workbook where it creates from the events work perfectly. My suspicion was the Application is retaining the application from that first notebook, is there a way to clear the stack for it and look at the new workbook that is created after I finished running the first function? thank you again for all your help!